# Error on Edit Object in entityframework An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of Entity ChangeTracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get an error when I call this text in my project. An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of Entity Change Tracker.

```
public static short Udf_Edit_Invoice(tblInvoice inv)
        {
            using (DbContextModel db = new DbContextModel())
            {
                using (DbContextTransaction transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (db.Entry<tblInvoice>(inv).State == EntityState.Detached)
                        {
                            db.Set<tblInvoice>().Attach(inv);
                        }

                        db.Entry<tblInvoice>(inv).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        transaction.Commit();
                        return 1;
                    }
                    catch(Exception ee)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Click Event: (And you can see the click event as follows, which was called inside a form and the information of the main class and the child class is poured into it, and then the editing command is called, which I encounter an error.)

```
 tblInvoice invtPub = new tblInvoice();
    private void Btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (TxtTax.Text == "")
                {
                    TxtTax.Text = "0";
                }
    
                Decimal Dec_TotalPrice = 0;
                Decimal Dec_TotalTakhfif = 0;
                
                Entities.Entity.tblInvoiceDetail invdObj;
                List<Entities.Entity.tblInvoiceDetail> invd = new List<Entities.Entity.tblInvoiceDetail>();
    
                foreach (DataRow Row in FactDt.Rows)
                {
                    invdObj = new Entities.Entity.tblInvoiceDetail();
                    Dec_TotalPrice += Decimal.Parse(Row["FoodTotalPrice"].ToString());
                    Dec_TotalTakhfif += Decimal.Parse(Row["FoodDiscount"].ToString());
                    invdObj.AssetID = int.Parse(Row["FoodID"].ToString());
                    invdObj.AssetQuantity = Double.Parse(Row["FoodQuantity"].ToString());
                    invdObj.Discount = Double.Parse(Row["FoodDiscount"].ToString());
                    invdObj.UnitPrice = Double.Parse(Row["FoodUnitPrice"].ToString());
                    invdObj.InvoiceID = 0;
                    invdObj.TotalPrice = Double.Parse(Row["FoodTotalPrice"].ToString());
                    invd.Add(invdObj);
                }
    
                invtPub.CreatorUserID = BLL.Class_GlobalVars.ThisPUserID;
                invtPub.CustomerID = long.Parse(Txt_CustomerCode.Text.Trim());
                invtPub.DateOfFactor = DateTime.Now;
                invtPub.InvoiceTitleID = 0;
                invtPub.IsCanceled = false;
                invtPub.PayCardOfInvoice = Decimal.Parse(Txt_Card.Text.Trim());
                invtPub.PayCashOfInvoice = Decimal.Parse(Txt_Cach.Text.Trim());
                invtPub.PayCredOfInvoice = (Decimal.Parse(Txt_Debit.Text.Trim()) < 0 ? Decimal.Parse(Txt_Debit.Text.Trim()) : 0);
                invtPub.PayDebtOfInvoice = (Decimal.Parse(Txt_Debit.Text.Trim()) >= 0 ? Decimal.Parse(Txt_Debit.Text.Trim()) : 0);
                invtPub.ShamsiDateOfFactor = ShamsiTools.Class_SHamsiTools.UDF_MiladiDateToShmasi(DateTime.Now);
                invtPub.StrDescription = Txt_Description.Text.Trim();
                invtPub.TaxOfInvoice = Decimal.Parse(TxtTax.Text.Trim());
                invtPub.TotalPriceOfFactor = Dec_TotalPrice;
                invtPub.TotalPriceOfFactorWithTax = (Decimal.Parse(TxtTax.Text) + Dec_TotalPrice);
                invtPub.tblInvoiceDetail = invd;
    
                if (Entities.Classes.Class_tblInvoice.Udf_Edit_Invoice(invtPub) == 1)
                {
                    Lbl_Total_Aglam.Text = "0";
                    Lbl_Total_Price.Text = "0";
                    Lbl_Total_Takhfif.Text = "0";
    
                    GrPr_Mohasebeh.Enabled = false;
                    Grpr_Custumer.Enabled = true;
                    Grpr_Factor.Enabled = true;
                    FactDt.Rows.Clear();
    
                    for (int i = FactDt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = FactDt.Rows[i];
                        {
                            dr.Delete();
                        }
                    }
    
                    Grd_Factor.DataSource = FactDt;
    
                    MessageBox.Show("Edited . . . . . .");
                    UDF_TXTFactorClear();
                    UDF_TXTCustomerClear();
                }
                else
                {
    
                }
            }
```

and total error message:

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.
"EntityFramework"

   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.VerifyContextForAddOrAttach(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachSingleObject(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntitySet entitySet)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Attach>b__9()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.set_State(EntityState value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1.set_State(EntityState value)
   at Entities.Classes.Class_tblInvoice.Udf_Edit_Invoice(tblInvoice inv) in E:\Programming\P1\ADVD9\TarkeEtiad\SourceCodeEF\Entities\Classes\Class_tblInvoice.cs:line 77
```

This:  tblInvoice invtPub = new tblInvoice();

```
[Table("tblInvoice")]
public partial class tblInvoice
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public tblInvoice()
    {
        tblInvoiceDetail = new HashSet<tblInvoiceDetail>();
    }

    [Key]
    public long InvoiceTitleID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Boolean IsCanceled { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CreatorUserID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long CustomerID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfFactor { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string ShamsiDateOfFactor { get; set; }
    public decimal? TotalPriceOfFactor { get; set; }
    public decimal TaxOfInvoice { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPriceOfFactorWithTax { get; set; }
    public decimal PayCashOfInvoice { get; set; } //نقدی
    public decimal PayCardOfInvoice { get; set; } //کارتخوان
    public decimal PayDebtOfInvoice { get; set; } //بدهی
    public decimal PayCredOfInvoice { get; set; } //طلب
    [MaxLength(1500)]
    public String StrDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual tblCustomers tblCustomers { get; set; }
    public virtual tblPUsers tblPUsers { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tblInvoiceDetail> tblInvoiceDetail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: this line:                          db.Entry<tblInvoice>(inv).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;  @Gert Arnold

Comment: What if you remove the entire `if` above it? Setting the state as modified will also attach `inv`.

Comment: I removed but I got error too: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.VerifyContextForAddOrAttach(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachSingleObject(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntitySet entitySet)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity)

Comment: at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Attach>b__9()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
\Class_tblInvoice.cs:line 77  @Gert Arnold

Comment: at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.set_State(EntityState value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbEntityEntry`1.set_State(EntityState value)
   at Entities.Classes.Class_tblInvoice.Udf_Edit_Invoice(tblInvoice inv) in E:\Programming\P1\ADVD9\TarkeEtiad\SourceCodeEF\Entities\Classes @Gert Arnold

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you have new info. Comments are hard to read. That said, this means that you do more with this `invtPub` than what happens in the event handler.

Comment: I edited and added total error @Gert Arnold

Comment: tblInvoice invtPub = new tblInvoice();
@Gert Arnold

Comment: Again. please remove your lengthy comments.

Comment: The code you show can't possibly attach `invtPub` to multiple contexts. Something else must be responsible for that.

Comment: it has relation @Gert Arnold . How do you think I can solve this problem? Do I have to manipulate the connection between the tables?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use any transactions since you only need to add one record.

try this

```
using (DbContextModel db = new DbContextModel())
{
   try
     {

 var existedInvoice=   db.Set<tblInvoice>().FirstOrDefault(i=> i.InvoiceTitleID = inv.InvoiceTitleID );
 if (existedInvoice!=null)
  {
  db.Entry(existedInvoice).CurrentValues.SetValues(inv);
  db.SaveChanges();

  return 1;

 } else return 0;

  }
      catch(Exception ee)
      {
     return 0;
        }
                
}
```